# How to search for a file on a remote system by file name using WMI in C#?

Tags: c#

How do I search for a file on a remote system by it's filename using WMI and C#?

Comment: Can you give _any_ more details on this?

Comment: as u may knw we can start and kill process in remote system using WMI. i wanto extnd this thing for getting the path of a file in remote system by searching usng file name as keyword...!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code and check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394594%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
Download also WMI Code Creator ( check on google because I can't link it due to my reputation <10)  to easily test your WMI query.

```
using System;
using System.Management;
namespace WMISample
{
    public class MyWMIQuery
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
            ConnectionOptions oConn = new ConnectionOptions(); 
            oConn.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate; 
            oConn.EnablePrivileges = true;
                string[] arrComputers = "clientName"};
                foreach (string strComputer in arrComputers)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("==========================================");
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer: " + strComputer);
                    Console.WriteLine("==========================================");


                        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher 
                        ( 
                           new ManagementScope("\\\\" + strComputer + "\\root\\CIMV2",  oConn), 
                           new ObjectQuery( @"SELECT * FROM CIM_DataFile WHERE Name = 'WhatyouWant.ToSearch'") 
                        ); 


                    foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                        Console.WriteLine("CIM_DataFile instance");
                        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                        Console.WriteLine("Path: {0}", queryObj["Path"]);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(ManagementException err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + err.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```